# Spring mongodb criteria regex number

Tags: spring, mongodb

Is there way to do regex search with spring mongodb on int field?

```
Criteria.where("carId").regex(searchQuery)
```

so when searchquery === 128 , it will query all documents that have car id starting with 128... 1283, 128888, 12823434 etc..